# Ошибка при запуске бота на heroku: "NameError: name 'os' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

```
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed

app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[worker.1]:   File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
app[worker.1]:     from api_helper import Api
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/api_helper.py", line 13, in <module>
app[worker.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
app[worker.1]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
app[worker.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
app[worker.1]:     self._setup(name)
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
app[worker.1]:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
app[worker.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
p[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
app[worker.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/settings.py", line 1, in <module>
app[worker.1]:     BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
app[worker.1]: NameError: name 'os' is not defined
heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

В `/app/settings.py`, судя по ошибке, не импортирован модуль `os` (`import os`), строка импорта должна находиться выше:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: что то не помогло

Comment: @NEOMC, перестаньте в ответах указывать комментарии/уточнения по вопросу. Для этого есть ваш вопрос (кнопка `править`). Должно было помочь. По стеку я вижу что у вас в `settings.py` в первой строке выполняется код с `BASE_DIR = ...`, если добавить выше импорт `os` как написал, то заработает. Если в ошибке снова пишет про `File "/app/settings.py", line 1,` значит вы что-то не так сделали, мб перезагрузить нужно

Comment: я добавил, но не работает

Comment: @NEOMC, ошибка такая же (выше я описывал на что нужно реагировать)? У вас могут быть еще ошибки